# Problems compiling in Lombok IntelliJ - mac, annotations enabled

Tags: android, macos, intellij-idea, annotations, lombok

I have the latest lombok.jar with plugin installed, downloaded and put it in libs in my project, setting up annotations via Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors -> Enable annotations

I am also running Android Annotations, with those annotation processing paths set specifically towards to the androidannotations-api-3.2.jar

Concerning the project, it is a clean import of a 1 year project that's not from eclipse/maven/gradle, and so it doesn't have gradle/maven with it. It is running on Java8 using Android SDK22.

The errors in compilation that I am getting as an example:

```
Error:(39, 16) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getName()
  location: variable p of type com.example.Property
```

I've recently switched from eclipse to IntelliJ, the project can be compiled on Eclipse but I think I am missing something with IntelliJ, thoughts?

Comment: Try removing the annotation processor and using the lombok idea plug-in. I use that daily without trouble

Comment: Problem is, is that annotation processing is required for Android Annotations, oh what a conundrum!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is making sure your project is structured in what gradle specifies, there are a multitude of answers here that will help provide you this information. Importing annotations as a dependency will also remove a lot of restrictions you may set on the project end.

Secondly, on the run configurations of the application, make sure that you add the "_" as your activity you plan on running because it has been annotated.